# JAVA multi-thread SocketServer how read data received one at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading

excuse my English, I'm asking because Java is not my primary language and I have spent quite some time on trying and some very poor results.

I need to make a multi-thread SocketServer. receiving the information submitted to the clients only receive the data and at some point post a reply.

the code I am using is the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
   Socket csocket;
   InputStream in;
   MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket) {
      this.csocket = csocket;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   throws Exception {
      ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1050);
      //System.out.println("Listening");
      while (true) {
         Socket sock = ssock.accept();
         new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(sock)).start();
         System.out.println("Connected");
      }
   }
   public void run() {
      try {
         PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(csocket.getOutputStream());
         for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
            //pstream.println(i + " bottles of beer on the wall");
         }
         pstream.close();
         csocket.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
}
```

is running well and is receiving data:

```
[root@ socket]# java MultiThreadServer
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
```

I need to read what I get because if there is connection of the equipment I was receiving in PHP on a string and then manipulated according to my need.

thanks for the help and sorry if I do something Undue is my first question. thank you all for your help as I have served enough on other issues.

Comment: So you want to read what the client sends you?

Comment: Correct devices send a various chain according to the model the idea is sending 50 simultaneous receive information every 2 to 3 minutes. Not Block line by line each is received

the total server memory was consumed by PHP with only 3 devices

JAVA is chosen so that it works the problem is that I do not understand the language for that reason aid pedi.

if you can explain step by step to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

To read what the client sends you, use a `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csocket.getInputStream()));

in.readLine(); // Read on line from the input.
```

Answer (score 0):

> package com.test;
>
> import java.io.*; import java.net.ServerSocket; import
>   java.net.Socket;
>
> public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
>       Socket csocket;
>       InputStream in;
>
> ```
> MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket) {
>     this.csocket = csocket;
> }
>
> public static void main(String args[])
>         throws Exception {
>     ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1050);
>     //System.out.println("Listening");
>     while (true) {
>         Socket sock = ssock.accept();
>         new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(sock)).start();
>         System.out.println("Connected");
>     }
> }
>
> public void run() {
>     try {
>         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csocket.getInputStream()));
>         while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
>             System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
>         }
>         bufferedReader.close();
>         csocket.close();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         System.out.println(e);
>     }
> } }
> ```